# LED lamp turns off when turned on

Tags: led, light, lamp

I just bought a new LED lamp and, when I turn it on, it slowly turns off in a few seconds. Why does it so that? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What make and model is this LED lamp?  It sounds rather...returnable to me.

Comment: It's a mainstay LED desk lamp

Answer (score 2):

The lamp is defective so return it for a replacement.

If you search on Google for "mainstay LED desk lamp" you will quickly see that this is a relatively inexpensive light and so trying to repair it is next to impractical. A light like this that directly connects to the AC mains:

[image]

...will have an electronic circuit board inside that converts the line voltage to the low voltage for the operation of the LED(s). That circuit appears to be bad and I can tell you that they are often really low quality so a faulty one is not surprising.

Comment: Um this is so weird this afternoon I turned it on to check if it would work and forgot to turn it off but after a while it turned on by itself and started working. I turned it off to check and it works perfectly fine now..